# mongo php insert with _id

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm having trouble assigning my own `_id` value when inserting a new document into my Mongo collection. Here's my PHP:

```
$user = array(
'_id'=> new MongoId("4f626fdf1771a8e71a000000"),
'name'=> 'John Smith'
)
try {
    if($col->insert($user)){
        echo 'INSERTED';
    }
} catch(MongoCursorException $e) {
    echo "ERROR: ".$e;
}
```

This does not display an error, but it also doesn't insert the item to the collection. However I can assign a string variable instead of the MongoId type to the `_id` field, and it inserts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, MongoDB driver runs commands in so called 'unsafe mode', when it does fire-and-forget for requests and does not check for error. So, if there's a duplicate key error, you won't know.

Try running the insert in safe mode like this:

```
$col->insert($user, array("safe" => true));
```

Oh, and you most certainly **can** make your own ObjectIds (contrary to what other answers here say).

Comment: Thanks! I was indeed receiving a duplicate key error! Was able to remove the duplicate key from my collection, and then insert my `_id` as a `MongoID` type object.

Answer (score 0):

Safe has been deprecated from future usage.  To ensure you are using the right command use the write concern 'w'.

$col->insert($user, array('w'=>true))

See here:
http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.insert.php

Answer (score -3):

You cannot [create MongoDB object](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification) IDs on your own. So, there are two ways to insert a document into a collection:

- Let MongoDB create the ID (safe!)
- Choose the ID on your own, it could be anything except an array and it needs to be unique.

Reference: [Object IDs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-The%5CidField)

I never used the combination of PHP and MongoDB but try to simple assign a string to the `_id` field.

Comment: Why exactly can't we generate ObjectIds by ourselves?

Comment: you could generate anything as ID, but ObjectIDs are generated with a certain schema (containing time, process id of the database, hostname..) by the MongoDB database, therefore you could not generate them.
To be more clear for the people which do not read the provided links:
ObjectIDs could only be generated by MongoDB, BUT you could set anything you want as an ID.

Comment: By MongoDB do you mean server?

Comment: Yes. MongoDB == the MongoDB database server process.

Comment: Then your statement is false. You can generate ObjectIds in the application code.

Comment: `$newMongoId = new MongoId('string');`